# Alexa echo show highlight text

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am creating a skill for Echo Show and was able to display text using BodyTemplate1. Now I wanted to highlight each word while Alexa utters those words. Could anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Not available yet. You can [vote](https://alexa.uservoice.com/forums/906892-alexa-skills-developer-voice-and-vote/suggestions/33793396-api-access-to-the-display-feature-that-follows-alo) the feature request up though.</strike>

This is available now using [APL (Alexa Presentation Language)](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/alexa-presentation-language/apl-overview.html). The [SpeakText directive](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/alexa-presentation-language/apl-standard-commands.html#speakitem-command) will accomplish what you want to do.